# Is it possible to show dynamic information in a Google Form based on a previous response?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I set up a form to specify the location of household appliances in a residence. The form is based on a unique code assigned to each household. (it's working properly)

To avoid entry errors, I would like that, once the unique code is entered, the user can see the detail of the device before confirming the new location.

The information is present in the associated Google spreadsheet, is it possible via a Google script to show it directly in the Form page?

Example:

```
Question 1: Select ID: E000025
-> Display: You're moving the SAMSUNG 32 "TV BLACK
Question 2: Select the new location: Apartment 200
```

Comment: No, this is not possible.  Once a Google Form has been opened, there is no way to provide dynamic user feedback.  You would need to design your own input form with HTML, CSS and JavaScript in an Apps Script Web App.

Comment: Hi Sandy, ok bad news... it seems to be a bit complicated for me. Is there any example of code of a such Apps script Web App that I can find ?

Comment: Here is an example:  [Apps Script File of Web App](https://drive.google.com/open?id=130r7K7TKLQJgVgl68Y9MBfRx4KGKA5HqPJCSeakB7PHygGzi-UFCP6aT)   Here is another:  [Contact Form - Web App](https://drive.google.com/open?id=125dG42eB9lM4SPq64p0dpR2CBH4ohfHiqu9TvFNM8s4Ra7pt-7kHXoTM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

No, it's not possible.

## Explanation

At this time Google Apps Script doesn't include a way to modify a form when a user open it to respond. An alternative is to use Google Apps Script to create a web app.

## References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: Hi Ruben, Thanks for your answer. Do you think I can do something with getIndex() and setHelpText(text) ? First to get the ID wich is selected and second to show details ?

Comment: @ClemT: Bear in mind that GAS could get the responses values after the form response be submitted. Please consider to post a new question.